# Proof including continuous function

Tags: calculus, continuity

**Question**
Let $f: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$  a continuous function.
Prove that

> $$\forall x \in \Bbb R\,\, \forall A >0\,\, \exists B>0\,\, \forall y \in \Bbb R\,\, |y-x|\le A : |f(x)-f(y)|\le B $$

**Thoughts**
At first I thought of trying to somehow define an inverse for f, but I realized I can't prove that one actually exists. A friend offered to set B to be $B=max{f(x)}-min{f(x)}$ . Is this a good direction?

Answer (score 3):

Hint: for a fixed $x$, note that $[x-A,x+A]$ is compact, and that the function $y\longmapsto |f(x)-f(y)|$ is continuous.

Note: your friend's suggestion works, provided you take these max and min over the interval $[x-A,x+A]$. But it is a bit less straightforward to check.